# Visual Studio Team Services clone command

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Im trying to find command for TFS like clone/checkout for GIT. I have regular TFVC version control system, NOT the *Git*. I have project on TFS and intranet server on which the my application works (it is php app no compilation is needed, only copy is required). I need to deploy changed files from TFS to intranet server. When i was using Git i only need to checkout changed files to server.

Is there any similar option how to do this on Visual Studio Team Services. I don't want to use deploy option in tfs. It is not possible to allow Visual Studio Team Services to access my intranet server (im looking for different way how to copy data on intranet server form TFS). And also i dont want to have full Visual Studio on my intranet server. Is there any option how to deploy changes from TFS to intranet server?

Comment: What's the TFS Online?Did you mean VS online?

Comment: `tf get`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio Team Services, you could try the [Xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true) command.

Include xcopy command in script, then add script into tfs git build process.

How to run script in your build process: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn376353(v=vs.120).aspx